# How to Change the default Cache First strategy to network first strategy in sw-precache?

Tags: sw-precache, sw-toolbox

Here is my gulp task :

```
 gulp.task('service-worker', ['clean:sw'], function (cb) {
swPrecache.write(path.join(global.config.offlineRoot, 'sw.js'), {
    staticFileGlobs: [
        global.config.offlineRoot + '/offline/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}',
        global.config.offlineRoot + '/manifest.json'
    ],
    dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
        '/app-shell': ['lib/views/layouts/app-shell.hbs'],
        '/': [
            'lib/views/layouts/main-layout.hbs',
            'lib/views/index.hbs'
        ]
    },
    runtimeCaching: [

        {
            // See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox#methods
            urlPattern: /^\/(?!login|admin)/,
            handler: 'networkOnly'
        }


    ],

    stripPrefix: global.config.offlineRoot,
    stripPrefixMulti: {
        "node_modules/": 'scripts/'
    },
    navigateFallback: '/app-shell',
    navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^\/(?!login|admin)/],
    cacheId: "nodebeats",
    //   importScripts: ['scripts/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js'],
    verbose: true,
    maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 3097152, //3mb
    handleFetch: true//(global.config.env === 'prod')
})
    .then(cb)
    .catch(function () {
        cb();
    });
```

});

From the above config, Login and admin route are fetched using network only and the index route is served from cache first, But I want it to be the network First since I am binding my page from the server side. So the dynamic data are not getting replicated in the app unless ctrl + f5

Answer (score 2):

For that use case, where your web content needs to be rendered on the server dynamically, I don't think `sw-precache` is a good fit. `sw-precache` can come in handy for [certain types](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/blob/master/GettingStarted.md#server-side-templating) of server-rendered resources, but only when the server-rendered content depends on one or more local partials/templates that are then composed on the server. (You'd set up that mapping via `dynamicUrlToDependencies`.)

For cases where the server-rendered content depends on something other than local templates/partials, like if it depends on the currently logged in user, `sw-precache` won't be of much help. You can use [`sw-toolbox`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) directly to handle this type of dynamic content if you'd like—something like the `networkFirst` strategy strikes a balance between providing a fresh response whenever there is a network connection, with the resiliency of falling back to the previous cached response when the network is unavailable.